# Non-indicator variable

Tags: regression, linearity

In OLS regression, do the control variables need to have linear relationship to the dependent variable (linearity assumption) or just the independent/explanatory variables? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

[Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) assumes a linear relationship between each independent (or explanatory) variable and the dependent variable$^1$. Typically, control variables are not contrasted with independent variables, as mathematically they are the same$^2$. You seem to be referring to certain independent variables as control variables because they are of less (or no) substantive interest. This is fine, just remember that **control variables are still independent variables**, despite not being of primary interest. Therefore, a linearity assumption is still being made.

For more information on regression and its assumptions, I highly recommend [Miles & Shevlin (2001)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0761962301) and Osborne & Waters (2019).

Also, thanks to @Richard Hardy for the suggestion, the assumption of linearity pertains to the linear relationship between the dependent variable $y=(y_1,...y_i,...,y_n)$ and each independent variable $x=(x_1,...,x_j,...,x_J)$. This means that the model predicts the dependent variable as a linear combination of the independent variables, or more specifically $y_{i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1}+\dots+\beta_{iJ}x_{iJ} + \epsilon_i$. The linearity assumption is with respect to the coefficients of the model (i.e., $\beta$) and not necessarily to the form of the variables. Thus, and as @Richard Hardy points out, transformations of the independent variables (e.g., $x^2$, $\log(x)$, $\cos(x)$) are still permitted.

$^1$ Note that this is also the case for multivariate regression, where there are more than 1 dependent variable.

$^2$ Thanks to @Dave in the comments for suggesting I clarify this.

**References**

Miles, J., & Shevlin, M. (2001). Applying regression and correlation: A guide for students and researchers. Sage.

Osborne, J. W., & Waters, E. (2019). Four assumptions of multiple regression that researchers should always test. *Practical Assessment, Research, and Evaluation*, 8(1), 2.

Comment: +1 “Control variable” just describes where the primary interest is (or isn’t). The math really couldn’t care less what we call a “control” variable.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for suggesting I clarify this. I was trying to speak to the language brian used in their question, though I think I improved my response.

Comment: $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\beta_2 x^2+\varepsilon$ is (still) a linear regression. You may want to phrase your answer to account for cases like this.

Comment: The way you phrase it sounds internally contradictory to me, but it is good that you draw the reader's attention to that.